# Socket won't send data after blocking queue .take()

Tags: java, android, tcp, termux

*Edit: I've found the problem ( see answer below )*

I'm trying to write an Android application to send data to a running `termux` instance via TCP.
In termux, I have netcat listening for incoming TCP connections and printing data to `stdout` using the command `nc -l localhost 8080`.

In my android app, I have a thread that reads in strings from a blocking queue and writes them out to a socket connectd to the address that netcat is listening on. The relevant code is the following:

```java
        runnable = () -> {
            Socket socket = null;
            OutputStream socketOutStream = null;
            while (running) {
                try {
                    if (null==socket) {
                        socket = new Socket();
                        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080), 2000);
                        socketOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        socketOutStream.write("Hello, Server!".getBytes()); // [1] Works!!
                        socketOutStream.flush();
                    }
                    String message = queue.take();
                    socketOutStream.write(message.getBytes()); // [2] Doesn't work!!?
                    socketOutStream.flush();
                    socketOutStream.close();
                    Log.i(TAG, "We wrote 'Button Clicked!' to the socket I think.");
                    // running=false;
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    socket = null;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Exiting socket sending loop.");
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
```

I'm trying to figure out why the initial data sent to netcat at the line marked `[1]` is actually received and displayed inside termux, but any subsequent data sent at `[2]` is not. The incoming strings fetched from the queue are certainly not empty.

Additionally, if I move the socket instantiation and connection logic to occurr until after `queue.take()` returns, I see a `SocketTimeoutException` via adb log output.

I would like to understand why it should make any difference whether either of these operations shoud occurr before or after the `queue.take()` operation returns.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a line terminator, depending on the requirements of `nc`. NB You don't need to `flush()` socket output streams unless there is a buffered stream or buffered writer.

Comment: I have tried with and without newlines at the end of sent messages and it doesn't make a difference. Moreover if `nc` expected to see a newline it wouldn't print out "Hello, Server!" which it in fact does do.

Comment: Are you sure the second message got enqueued? and that you aren't just blocked in `take()`?

Comment: Yes because the log line below the `take()` call comes back across ADB shell. 
After further investigation I suspect this has something to do with the fact that this thread is running inside of a service, and the main activity that launches the service exits right after launching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to resolve the issue with the TCP socket hanging by attaching the socket to a **foreground service** as opposed to a **background service** which is how it was running in the first instance. It seems Android background services are liable to have TCP communications delayed or buffered in order to economize battery usage.